# DJANGO Update field of all objects in a table on save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to update one boolean field of all objects in an email table, but i need to do this when one email gets saved. I have an object named Vendor and other named Client, both can have multiple Email's, (Email/Client has OneToMany Relation to emails) this is my Email model:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    main = models.BooleanField("(Main)", default=False)
    address = models.CharField("Email address")

    limit = models.Q(app_label='store', model='store') | models.Q(app_label='core', model='client')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     limit_choices_to=limit,
                                     verbose_name="Related Object Type")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Related Object ID")
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'info'
```

As you can see email have a genericforeignkey, because they can belong to vendor or client model, the main field means that this email is the main of the related object, only 1 email of each related object can have main = True.

My approach was to override the save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    emails = Email.objects.filter(content_type__pk=self.content_type.id, object_id=self.object_id, main=True)
    for email in emails:
        email.main = False
        email.save()
    self.main = True
    super(Email, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is: 
When i try to save an email i query for all emails to set the main field to false, but i need to save the object modified, it ends calling the save function again giving me error.

Is there any way to do this without infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calling `update`, which just updates the fields, and does not call the `save`.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    Email.objects.filter(content_type__pk=self.content_type.id, object_id=self.object_id, main=True).update(main=False)

    self.main = True
    super(Email, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the [documentation on `update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)